# Transform Data colums into rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I have a df like this:

```
ValueA ValueB ID
0.10   1.00   1
0.15   2.00   2 
0.25   4.00   3
```

and so on. I need to transform this df into an output like this:

```
ID Value X 
1  ValueA 0.10
1  ValueB 1.00    
2  ValueA 0.15
2  ValueB 2.00
3  ValueA 0.25
3  ValueB 4.00
```

How can I do this with R? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `cbind(df[3], stack(df[-3]))`

Comment: This works perfect thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the `reshape2` package, you can do:

```
> reshape2::melt(mydata, id = "ID", variable = "Value", value.name = "X")
  ID  Value    X
1  1 ValueA 0.10
2  2 ValueA 0.15
3  3 ValueA 0.25
4  1 ValueB 1.00
5  2 ValueB 2.00
6  3 ValueB 4.00
```

Comment: also a working solution. Thanks